# responsive menu (div is too small after click event)

Tags: html

So I have a menu which is putted on header with background colour. After resize (max width 1044 px) it turns on mobile menu and the div that holds menu and anchors is just to small comparing to the header.

Any solution?

Comment: Could you please share your header and menu HTML+CSS code? It's quite hard to help without seeing any snippet.

Comment: Heres the snippet http://jsfiddle.net/2quLdo3a/

Comment: Ok thanks. What do you mean exactly with "the div is to small"? What is your desided behaviour?

Comment: When you click menu - the div that contains all links should be max width, you can see on snippet theres some background, (white), I need when click toggle on menu the div which contains links should cover entire page from left to right. its seems its just too much centered its too small.

Comment: Ok, it's clear now. Give me some time to elaborate a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've completely redesigned your layout, I think it's much simpler and comprehensive now. The key for the problem is to include everything (including `nav` and `handle`) inside `header` block, which is 100% width.

```
<header>
    <div class="logo">
        <img class="image" src="img/lion-logo" alt="lion-logo" />
        <div class="text">
            <div class="name">LIONET</div>
            <div class="description">Web design agency</div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <a class="handle" href="#">Menu</a>

    <nav>
        <a class="item" href="#">home</a>
        <a class="item" href="#">process</a>
        <a class="item" href="#">workflow</a>  
        <a class="item" href="#">about</a>   
        <a class="item" href="#">blog</a> 
        <a class="item" href="#">contact</a>    
    </nav>

</header>
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/2quLdo3a/3/)

Furthermore, I've centered logo when you are in mobile-mode (I like it more, but you can remove it if you want). Let me know if it works.